# How can ImmutableMap builder create instance of abstract class?

Tags: java, guava

I am learning to use guava library and referred to [this](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) I see use of builder to construct an instance of immutable map. How is the builder constructor able to create an abstract class instance?

```
   static final ImmutableMap<String, Integer> WORD_TO_INT =
       new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Integer>()
           .put("one", 1)
           .put("two", 2)
           .put("three", 3)
           .build();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ImmutableMap (Guava: Google Core Libraries for Java 21.0-SNAPSHOT API)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) states that it is "a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html?is-external=true) whose contents will never change, with many other important properties detailed at [`ImmutableCollection`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableCollection.html)".

The "other important properties detailed at [`ImmutableCollection`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableCollection.html)" include the following **guarantees**:

> Each makes the following guarantees:
>
> - **Shallow immutability.** Elements can never be added, removed or replaced in this collection. This is a stronger guarantee than that of [`Collections.unmodifiableCollection(java.util.Collection<? extends T>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html?is-external=true#unmodifiableCollection-java.util.Collection-), whose contents change whenever the wrapped collection is modified.
> - **Null-hostility.** This collection will never contain a null element.
> - **Deterministic iteration.** The iteration order is always well-defined, depending on how the collection was created (see the appropriate factory method for details). View collections such as [`Multiset.elementSet()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html#elementSet--) iterate in the same order as the parent, except as noted.
> - **Thread safety.**  It is safe to access this collection concurrently from multiple threads.
> - **Integrity.** This type cannot be subclassed outside this package (which would allow these guarantees to be violated).

The last guarantee, **integrety**, alludes to the fact that internally Guava has concrete implementations (non-abstract) of `ImmutableMap` and other immutable objects which is what is actually returned by these builders.

Furthermore, the source is open; you can go find out for yourself *how* the builder is able to do it (e.g. you might start [here](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.java#L191-L362)).

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. Yes, build() seems to be creating RegularImmutableMap instance.

Answer (score 1):

I does not, the *Builder* creates an *implementation of* an `ImmutableMap` (a class that `extends` the `ImmutableMap`).

To understand clearly, start [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html) before working with Guava.

Update: see comment by @Louis Wasserman. Indeed an essential comment.

Comment: Thanks for the link and confirming that it doesnt :) The documentation didnot indicate it was subclassing or which subclass type it would build. Hence my question.

Comment: As far as the user concerned, it shouldn't matter, and there's no guarantee how that implementation will change later.  That's the point of a factory pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the **constructor** of the builder class that returns an instance of an immutable map.

You are first creating the builder by calling `new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Integer>()` and then you are calling methods in a chain on this `ImmutableMap.Builder` instance - three times the `put` method and then the `build` method.

The `build` method is what is called last, and that is what creates and returns the instance of `ImmutableMap`.

The "trick" here is that the `put` method of `ImmutableMap.Builder` returns the builder itself (it has a statement `return this;` at the end) so that you can chain method calls like this.

And, indeed, the `build` method returns an instance of a subclass of `ImmutableMap` because class `ImmutableMap` is abstract, so it cannot be directly instantiated.